# wrappanel didnot resize properly

Tags: wpf

I have a user control like this

```
<ListBox x:Class="ColorPickerDemo.Controls.ColourRampListBox"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     Width="auto">

<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

<ListBoxItem>
    <Rectangle x:Name="ColourRectangleYR" Width="85" Height="40" Margin="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</ListBoxItem>
```

And i am using in a window like

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="350"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>      

    <GroupBox Header="Preset Colour Gradients" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <local:ColourRampListBox Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>  
</Grid>
```

But i am getting output as like

[image: this]

But i want this

[image]

I am not able to figure out what's going wrong.
Please help in this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Width` of your `Panel` is not fixed so it will expand till infinite. :)

**try below:** ***(for Dynamic width)***

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Perfect man. Thank you so much. Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For wrappanel have to specify the maxwidth, in this case the Width of the ListBox that encloses it.

E.g.

```
<WrapPanel MaxWidth="300"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.